# What changes in the execution of an iron router route when coming in on a deep link?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a small meteor app going with iron router.  Here's my routes.js, which is available to both client and server:

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'defaultLayout',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading'
});

// Map individual routes    
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('comicCreate', {
    path: '/comic/create'
  });

  this.route('comicDetails', {
    onBeforeAction: function () {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    },
    path: '/comic/:_id',
    layoutTemplate: 'youtubeLayout',
    data: function() { return Comics.findOne(this.params._id); }
  });

  this.route('frontPage', {
    path: '/',
    layoutTemplate: 'frontPageLayout'
  });

  this.route('notFound', {
    path: '*',
    where: 'server',
    action: function() {
      this.response.statusCode = 404;
      this.response.end('Not Found!');
    }
  });    
});
```

I need to feed some fields from my comic collection document into a package that wraps Youtube's IFrame API, and I'm doing this via the rendered function:

```
Template.comicDetails.rendered = function() {
  var yt = new YTBackground();

  if (this.data)
  {
    yt.startPlayer(document.getElementById('wrap'), {
      videoIds: this.data.youtubeIds,
      muteButtonClass: 'volume-mute',
      volumeDownButtonClass: 'volume-down',
      volumeUpButtonClass: 'volume-up'
    });
  }    
};
```

This works great when I start by going to localhost:3000/ and then clicking on a link set to "{{pathFor 'comicDetails' _id}}".  However, if I go directly to localhost:3000/comic/somevalidid, it doesn't, despite the fact that both routes end up pointing me at the same url.

The reason appears to be that when I go directly to the deep link, "this.data" is undefined during the execution of the rendered function.  The template itself shows up fine (data correctly replaces the spacebars {{field}} tags in my template), but there's nothing in the "this" context for data when the rendered callback fires.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

try declaring the route in Meteor.startup ... not sure if that's the problem but worth a try